# Unable to Override C-M-t Keybinding

Tags: key-bindings

I have a weird problem;)

```
(defun hello-world ()
  "Insert snippet."
  (interactive)
  (insert "Hello World")
  )
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-t") 'hello-world)
```

This doesn't work, as C-M-t is still bound to org-transpose-element.

It works however if I do

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-r") 'hello-world)
```

, so is there something special with t here?;)

Comment: I assume you're testing C-M-t inside an org-mode buffer: local bindings take precedence over global bindings, Use `local-set-key` or `keymap-set` or `define-key` instead

Comment: https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/mastering-key-bindings-emacs is recommended reading.

Comment: Indeed;) Should've tried to unset it first;). Thanks

Comment: If this is a duplicate question or you don't think the question will help others, consider deleting it. If it's worth keeping then it's likely worth having an answer, in which case, consider posting one, perhaps based on comments.